# UML: multiplicity of qualifier

Tags: uml

What is the meaning of multiplicity of the qualifier in the current UML standard? Can it ever be anything other than 1?

UPDATE:

Suppose the association is: [Library](qualifier: library code) <-> [Book], and the qualifier multiplicity is 1..5.

Does it mean that each book in this library is tagged by between 1 and 5 library codes, or does it mean that there are between 1 and 5 of each book in the library, each of which is marked by 1 code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The qualifier is a property. Like with any other property, its multiplicity specifies the number of values needed for a correct assignment.

In case of a qualifier, you could for example specify that the qualifier value needs to be a list of 5 strings or similar.

And even a lower bound of 0 might make sense to represent an empty qualifier value (like a null together with an upper bound of 1, or an empty collection for a higher upper bound).

UPDATE:

If the multiplicity of 1..5 is defined for the qualifier "library code", then this means that every book is qualified by 1 to 5 library codes, i.e. you need to specify between 1 and 5 codes in order to navigate this association from a Library to a Book.

If on the other hand the multiplicity of 1..5 is specified on the association end for the book, it means that for any given qualifier value, there are between 1 and 5 books in the library.

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify a bit based on my update to the question?